# How to find more than 7 specific symbol in a line?

Tags: notepad++

i have some text data in Notepad++ as below, I want to find the rows which having greater than 7 `;` (semicolons) and after the 7th semicolon  the line should move to next line.

```
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;kasjdjkashd;
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;skdjjd;
```

output should be:

```
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;
jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;
jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;kasjdjkashd;
sdkjfkdf;asdkjfhkhsdf;sdjfhkhkf;sadjfhks;dhhdhd;jfksdf;dfhkk;
jhdfkksdf;kjdfhksf;skdjjd;
```

And question 2 is :

The lines which are not starting with numbers should be moved to previous line end.

```
1237;sdkjjf;djdkd;djfhfk;
sjdjdjd;skks;
12344;sjdjjd;djdjjd;
*ddjdjdj
.sjjs;
#jdjjdjd
```

output should be:

```
1237;sdkjjf;djdkd;djfhfk;sjdjdjd;skks; 
12344;sjdjjd;djdjjd;*ddjdjdj.sjjs;#jdjjdjd
```

Comment: Can we do the second question in notepad ++

Comment: Please, avoid to ask 2  questions at the same time, especially when they can't be answered in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

## For the first question:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.+?;){7}\K`
- Replace with: `\n` or `\r\n` for Windows EOL
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (?:       # non capture group
    .+?     # 1 or more any character but newline
    ;       # semicolon
  ){7}      # end group, must appear 7 times
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## For the second question:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!\d)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]